# AWS Cognito user activity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I use Cognito on a website to do few things like: invoke an API gateway or create an entry on DynamoDB.

Do you know if there is a tool or way to record and track the user activity on the infrastructure side ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you understand under *activity on the infrastructure*? Purpose of AWS Cognito is completely different

Comment: I want to track the usage of the Cognito users. Not only statistics, but record the actions they are doing

Comment: You may have a look at AWS CloudTrail. You can enable the CloudTrail service on your account and all AWS API calls will be logged

Comment: You should us Pinpoint.